# CHAR(10) sometimes work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

IN SQL

I want to print for example

```
Ali 
is going to Alex
```

so I said

declare @x varchar(max)
set @x = 'Ali' + CHAR(10) + 'is going to Alex'

the output appear in one line instead of two ones

in some servers it work very well in tohers not even with using CHAR(13)

any idea how to fix that

Comment: What does "not work" mean? What are "some servers"? Are you displaying the data on a web page, in results to grid, in results to text, something else?

Comment: the output appear in one line instead of two ones

Comment: The output appear where?

Comment: in either outputresult part on asp.net

Comment: If the output is HTML then instead of `CHAR(10)` use an HTML tag (e.g. `<br>`). If the output is not HTML, then please provide more information. Pulling teeth is boring.

Comment: I simply use it in string , and want to see \n in the string

Comment: Then put `'\n'` in the string.

Comment: try `PRINT @x` just to confirm that it works

Comment: @AMH The string has the `\n`. What is shown on the output depends on the application that outputs. If (could) you send the output to `/dev/null`, I'm sure you'd see nothing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a proper CR+LF pair, you should use:

```
declare @x varchar(max); 
set @x = 'Ali' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'is going to Alex'
```

Now, how that gets translated in wherever you are looking in your ASP page, I have no idea. If you want `\r\n` etc. to appear in the string, then perhaps you should consider using those values instead of `CHAR(10)`.